# How to bypass server authentication in SVN/Subclipse

Tags: authentication, svn, ssh, subclipse

I have set up an SVN server on a remote system. I can connect to it fine using svn+ssh://

However Subclipse prompts me for 2 levels of authentication. The first being the username and password to ssh into the system and the second is the username and passwords defined in the SVN password file.

Some of our developers do not require ssh access and we do not want to provide them with the password. As such, they cannot get past the first level of authentication.

Is there any way to bypass the ssh authentication and use only the SVN password file when checking in and checking out projects from the repository?

Edit: it actually seems like the second level of authentication isn't even doing anything. it checks for a valid user, but lets them put anything in as a password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them a locked-down account and a public key file. This provides a password-less login which they can use to send SVN commands through. Because your SVN requires a password they will still receive this prompt.

You can do some pretty draconian things with the ssh account like revoking write permission to their home directory and setting a very short timeout.

You can have as many public keys for this one account as you like and can distribute them to your developers. The advantage of this is that you can always revoke one of the keys later without affecting the others.

See here for more information:
https://blog.tinned-software.net/subversion-via-ssh-using-authorized_keys

You could also try setting the login for the account as /usr/bin/svn instead of an interactive shell. This may be the simplest and most secure method if it works for your check-in process.